# Automatic cell increase

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am building a spreadsheet and would like a way to automatically increase the cells in column A dependent on whether a user name is entered into Column B. For example:

If A1 = `R-0001` and B1 = `Sarah` then when a new user enters their name in Column B I would  like A2 = `R-0002` etc etc

Can anyone help with a macro or alternative that will do this?

Comment: Is it OK when the value of the 'A-cell' corresponds with the row number? So A1 = R-0001, A2 = R-0002 and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a cell formula. In A1 enter `=If(B1<>"", "R-" & Text(Row(), "0000"), "")` and copy that down however many rows you believe you may have names for.

A quick break down of what this formula does:

1. First it test if B1 has a value (when you copy this down it will test B2, B3, B4, etc..
2. If it has a value then it concatenates "R-" with Row number
3. The `Text(Row(), "0000")` bit insures that your Row number that is returned is 4 digits. Cell `A1` will produce `0001` where Cell A532 will produce `0532`
4. If B1 is empty than A1 will also be empty

Comment: @pnuts I should really make better use of tables. I'm still in the mindset of `=offset(a1, 0, 0, counta(a1:A999999), 2)` named ranges... which can be a bit of a beast to manage and do nothing for automagically copying down formulas.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in a formulaic way, you can set the contents of A1 to be

```
"R-"&TEXT(ROW(),"0000")
```

which would make the value R-(rownumber), with a fixed with of at least 4. It is probably the most simplistic way of doing this.